# Web service call lost value other than string

Tags: c#, android, web-services, soap, xamarin

I'm developing an android app that comunicate with SOAP web service. I'm  using method generated by wsdl file.
Unfortunetly web services receives only string values in xml, not bool, integer or decimal. In Fiddler i noticed  that app not sending this (decimal, ets.)values so i think that is bug in my side not  web service. In SOAPUI everything wokrs perfect. My code is something like this:

```
WebService service = new WebService();
service.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
          service.SoapVersion =System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapProtocolVersion.Soap11;
Order ord = new Order {
value1 = 1,
value2 = "value2",
value3= false,
};
service.addOrder(ord);
```

Anyone know where could be a problem?